# Using SVN with CodeBlocks Projects

Tags: svn, codeblocks

I have an SVN repository setup online and I want to use it to manage my C++ projects in CodeBlocks.

I read that SVN can only track changes to text files, so how do I manage the .cbp project files and other non-text files. Do CodeBlocks projects have a way to checkout files from the repository and deal with changes? Or should I commit everything as a whole project including all non-text files and the .cbp file?

Sorry if this question is a bit vague.

Thanks, Ash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually SVN is able to track history of files with any content.
Text files only make it easier to analyse changes and compress them during storage, but there is not effects on ability to see history, branching and so on.

For some types of binary data specialized tools may exist which allow conveniently see differences and do merges on client side.

For example on doc-files, by default TortoiseSVN launches Word to show differences

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder named CB-Project (or a name you like)in the same directory you have the SVN in.  You will have to set your path so the new project file name is in it.  You can name a project (garbage) or any name you'd like code::blocks will add the file extension for you. You can have many projects and different versions of them.